# Make an autoclicker to dial keystrings

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to make an app which will dial keystrings for me in phone dialer.

On clicking button in an app the app goes in background and open phone app and by autoclicking it will dial keystring.

Answer (score -1):

Even if you can auto click call button on different phone are positioned in different positions. If you want to make a call from your app you can just use Intent

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+8802177690));//change the number  
startActivity(callIntent);
```

and add to your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: But keystrings like *#06# didn't work. I just want to dial keystrings by auto clicking

Comment: Uri.parse("tel:*#06#")